# How to execute multiple batch files one by one in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I have two batch files. The first one is to download files from SFTP. The second is to manipulate some local files. Since I have to wait until the first one is finished, how to hold the program in VBA so the batch files can be executed one by one?

Right now I am using

```
Call Shell("Bat1.bat")
Call Shell("Bat2.bat")
```

However, two batch files will be executed at the same time. `Bat2.bat` will not wait `Bat1.bat`.

Thanks

Comment: What is the code which has you stuck right now?

Comment: @Brad I added some explanation.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/3980918/vba-check-if-specific-process-task-id-is-still-running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, drop the `Call` statement, it's not needed.

```
Shell "Bat1.bat"
```

Make `Bat1.bat` create an empty "marker" file when it's done, e.g. `bat1.ready`. Then make your VBA code loop until it can find that `.ready` file:

```
While Dir("bat1.ready") = vbNullString
    DoEvents
Wend
```

This should keep your UI/host app responsive, while essentially doing nothing until the marker file is up.

Next you delete the marker file and proceed with `bat2`:

```
Kill "bat1.ready"
Shell "Bat2.bat"
```

Ta-da!

---

The `Shell` function [returns immediately](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278437.aspx), and returns the created TaskID. If you can't modify the batch file in any way (or ask whoever can modify it if they could do that), then you'll probably need to use some Win32 calls to use that TaskID to determine whether the task has completed, as in the [ShellAndWait](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx) link that Tim Williams provided [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601699/how-to-execute-multiple-batch-files-one-by-one-in-vba/37602205?noredirect=1#comment62689573_37601699)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing is `Bat1.bat` cannot be modified by me. I don't have the authorization to modify that. Is there some way that we can do this without modifying `Bat1.bat` ?

Comment: @NewGuyComesIn edited. hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Still mark yours as answer.